# ubuntu 22.04 Cannot go into settings

Tags: kubuntu

I just upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04. I cannot go into settings. I click wi fi settings or power settings and nothing is happening. I tried to shut down or restart the pc, nothing. Same happens. Any solutions? Thanks!

Comment: Try from command line and post the output by [edit]ing your original question.

Comment: things like this can happen when you remove or purge some package ... always take note of the message which lists all packages such a command will remove and avoid shooting from the hip when removing packages ... although no matter how compromised the resultant laptop/desktop ( not server )  becomes you can boot it up into `recovery mode` then from there enable `networking` and choose the fix packages option ...  then pick the root terminal option to issue commands to reinstall any missing packages or clean up in general

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and solved it with:

```
sudo apt purge gnome-control-center
sudo apt install gnome-control-center
```

After a reboot all the settings menus where back in place.